# Finding the Unknown Coordinate when given Distances from two points

Tags: geometry

I have this problem that I don't know how to do.

> Locate the two points that are $5$ units from $(5,-3)$ and square root of $41$ units from$(-2,6)$

Comment: Can you write down an equation satisfied by the point 5 units from $(5,-3)$?

Comment: **Hint**: $ \text{Distance}  = \sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^{2} + (y_2 - y_1)^{2} }$

Answer (score 1):

You need the intersection of two circles.

Let's say $A=(5,-3)$ and $B=(-2,6)$, $r_1=5$ and $r_2=\sqrt{41}$.

Now

$$c_1:(x-5)^2+(y+3)^2=5^2 \quad and \quad c_2:(x+2)^2+(y-6)^2=\sqrt{41}^2$$

Now you have to find you [radical axis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis) of $c_1,c_2$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
c_1-c_2&:x^2-10x+y^2+6y+9=0 \\ 
&-[x^2+4x+y^2-12y-1=0]\\
&\Rightarrow z(x)=\frac 7 9 x - \frac 5 9
\end{eqnarray*}

With $z(x) \cap c_1$ you'll get

$$(x-5)^2+(z(x)+3)^2=25$$ with $L=\lbrace \frac{121}{65}, 2 \rbrace$ for $x$. So your two points are $S_1(\frac{121}{65};\frac{58}{65})$ and $S_2(2;1)$

Comment: Your notation is very confusing. You use $x$ for multiple things I guess and you are effectively asking to solve $5^2=\sqrt{41}^2$. Please consider rewriting your answer.

Comment: How can you write $c_1(x)$ when it's a function of both $x$ and $y$? And how can you set $5^2$ and $\sqrt{41}^2$ equal?

Comment: added some information